# USB HID keyboard: why 4 URBs are generated for a keypress instead of 2?

Tags: usb, keyboard, hid

This is system log when keyboard is plugged in:

```
usb 5-1: new low-speed USB device number 7 using uhci_hcd
usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=0103
usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
input: HID 04f3:0103 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:04F3:0103.000D/input/input23
hid-generic 0003:04F3:0103.000D: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [HID 04f3:0103] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
input: HID 04f3:0103 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:04F3:0103.000E/input/input24
hid-generic 0003:04F3:0103.000E: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [HID 04f3:0103] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1
```

Then I run `wireshark` and press a key. But instead of 2 URBs there are 4. What part of the URB contains the pressed key code and what for are two extra URBs? Here is the [trace](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8fpi978v96ms6i/kbd.pcapng?dl=1).

These are images, one per packet:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: Is it possible for you to post trace as image?

Comment: @MaNyYaCk Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of packets shown:

`URB type: URB_COMPLETE`:  This is clearly sent from the device and contains the key data.

`URB type: URB_SUBMIT` : This is the host (hid driver) asking for the *next* data packet.  Note that source is host and destination is device, which would otherwise be invalid for an IN type packet on the USB bus.

Comment: But why there are two reqest-response pairs instead of one? Is it documented in HID spec?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko (KeyPress) followed by (KeyRelease)